# Unable to open MSQL Server 2017 Installation Center

Tags: .net, windows, sql-server-2017, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to open SQL Server 2017 Installation Center in Windows 2019 DC edition. The DotNet Framework Version is 4.7.

Whenever we click on MSSQL Installation Center, it crashes right away. Below are the error logs from Event Viewer

Application Error:

```
Faulting application name: LandingPage.exe, version: 14.0.3401.7, time stamp: 0x60d64563
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3875.0, time stamp: 0x6137d473
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000078613
Faulting process id: 0x2b40
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8063f59e2ecdf
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\SQL2017\x64\LandingPage.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: ba991ba5-a498-40ec-8737-ae5358dd3ead
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

.Net Runtime:
Application: LandingPage.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF97D468613 (00007FF97D3F0000) with exit code 80131506.
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Sure seems that .NET is not happy.  Reinstall .NET?  Reboot the machine?

Comment: Thank you! I will do that and update you.